# wpf textbox focus issue

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

I have a control with several textbox controls on it.

Now, when I press tab after I edit one of the textboxes, the focus is switched to the next textbox BUT I need to press an additional tab in order for it to enter the "editing" stage.

The first tab simply draws a dotted background on the textbox ... and the second one actually puts the cursor position inside the textbox. Is there a way when I press tab, to automatically set the cursor inside the textbox?

Thanks./

Comment: Never had such a behaviour. But try set TabIndex and IsTabStop=true, maybe that will help.

Comment: My crystal ball says that there is an additional control around your TextBox which takes focus. Please show a (small) XAML snippet that can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: this is not the default behavior, that what you would like to is default. try to set the properites to default values Or there is somthing under/over that control (dots arounds)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you sure you don't have any hidden controls or other controls that might be accepting focus before your textbox? Either way, you should be able to update the tabindex value of your controls so they follow a logical sequence when tab is pressed.